# Use of pandas.shift() to align datasets based on scipy.signal.correlate

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I have datasets that look like the following: [data0](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3108bf789f37c7d48efa), [data1](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bff59ebf9c0b197ca37e), [data2](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/733013b8b8752cdcf876) (analogous to time versus voltage data)

If I load and plot the datasets using code like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
from matplotlib import pylab as plt

data0 = pd.read_csv('data0.csv')
data1 = pd.read_csv('data1.csv')
data2 = pd.read_csv('data2.csv')

plt.plot(data0.x, data0.y, data1.x, data1.y, data2.x, data2.y)
```

I get something like:

[image: plotting all three datasets]

now I try to correlate data0 with data1:

```
shft01 = np.argmax(signal.correlate(data0.y, data1.y)) - len(data1.y)
print shft01
plt.figure()
plt.plot(data0.x, data0.y,
         data1.x.shift(-shft01), data1.y)
fig = plt.gcf()
```

with output:

```
-99
```

and

[image: shifted version of data1]

which works just as expected! but if I try it the same thing with data2, I get a plot that looks like:

[image: shifted version of data2]

with a positive shift of `410`. I think I am just not understanding how `pd.shift()` works, but I was hoping that I could use `pd.shift()` to align my data sets. As far as I understand, the return from `correlate()` tells me how far off my data sets are, so I should be able to use shift to overlap them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`panda.shift()` is not the correct method to shift curve along x-axis. You should adjust X values of the points:

```
plt.plot(data0.x, data0.y)
for target in [data1, data2]:
    dx = np.mean(np.diff(data0.x.values))
    shift = (np.argmax(signal.correlate(data0.y, target.y)) - len(target.y)) * dx
    plt.plot(target.x + shift, target.y)
```

here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That makes a lot of sense. I guess I was unclear as to how `pd.shift()` worked based on the documentation available.

Answer (score 5):

[@HYRY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/772649/hyry) one correction to your answer: there is an indexing mismatch between `len()`, which is one-based, and `np.argmax()`, which is zero-based. The line should read:

`shift = (np.argmax(signal.correlate(data0.y, target.y)) - (len(target.y)-1)) * dx`

For example, in the case where your signals are already aligned:

`len(target.y)` = N (one-based)

The cross-correlation function has length 2N-1, so the center value, for aligned data, is:

`np.argmax(signal.correlate(data0.y, target.y)` = N - 1 (zero-based)

`shift = ((N-1) - N) * dx` = (-1) * dx, when we really want 0 * dx

Comment: Nice! This helped me when I tried to find an equivalent  `alignsignals` method in Python after switching from Matlab.